# Cannot find DVD drive under 'My Computer'

Tags: drivers, dvd

I have two DVD drives on my computer. I can open them an put in DVD's by pushing the button on them. However, the DVD's I put in don't autoplay. I cannot navigate to them because I dont see them under 'My Computer'.

The Operating System is Windows Vista.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've got power running, so check if the cables are connected.

Since you are running Windows Vista you should check the device manager. (*Control Panel > Hardware & Sound > Device Manager*)

Check under DVD/CD-ROM Drives if the devices are displayed.

If they don't show up try *Action > Scan for Hardware changes*

If they do show up right click the devices and select update drivers. Maybe reboot and try again.

The last thing that may be happening is that they work as normal, but the problem is that Disk Management doesn't assign a drive letter to the drives. To fix this issue you should start the Disk Manager.

*Start > Search for* "Windows Disk Management"

Then scroll down to the drives and see if they get a drive letter assigned. If they don't right click them and select "Assign drive letter and Paths" then select the drive letter of your choice. Now you should get promted.

Comment: The data cables weren't connected. Actually couldn't be connected because the motherboard required the newer SATA cables which the older DVD drives did not have.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can open the trays, they are getting power; so I suspect the DVD drive data cables. Check if they are properly connected to your motherboard. Make sure that you seated both data cables into their sockets correctly.

If you are on Windows, use this [Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/hardware_device_problems) link to detect your problem.

Comment: The data cables weren't connected. Actually couldn't be connected because the motherboard required the newer SATA cables which the older DVD drives did not have.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the obvious - are the drives connected to the motherboard correctly? You've obviously got power, but the data cables might missing or not plugged in correctly.

If they are then the next likely cause is missing drivers, but as you don't say what operating system you've got I can't suggest a solution.

Comment: The data cables weren't connected. Actually couldn't be connected because the motherboard required the newer SATA cables which the older DVD drives did not have.